# SQL Pairing Columns from one Table

Tags: sql, duplicates, derby

I need to pair 2 supplier names via the city they are located in.

```
<name supplier a> <name supplier b> <location>
```

I got that form via Crossjoining the one Supplier table - now I need to secure that it is only one record - so either this in the code blockk top or:

```
 <name supplier b> <name supplier a> <location>
```

Example:

Märzen AG  |  Maier KG  |  Ulm

OR

Maier KG |  Märzen AG  |  Ulm

Thus: I need only one of the above results.
At the moment I get both records out of the Crossjoin:

```
 SELECT le.Liefname, le.liefstadt, li.Liefname
 FROM Lieferanten le CROSS JOIN Lieferanten li
 WHERE le.Liefstadt not like '' 
 AND li.Liefstadt not like '' 
 AND le.liefstadt=li.liefstadt;
```

Where liefstadt is the city that pairs them and liefname is the name I need to output.

Another approach I wanted to do is:

```
SELECT a.LiefName, b.LiefName, LiefStadt 
FROM Lieferanten a, Lieferanten b 
WHERE     a.LiefStadt = b.LiefStadt 
AND a.LiefName <> b.LiefName;
```

problem here is that there are still duplicates in the results.

I hope I could say enough to make you understand my problem as I am not a native speaker. (And thus might have missed an already existing topic that'd help me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tweak your first approach:

```
SELECT le.Liefname, le.liefstadt, li.Liefname
 FROM Lieferanten le CROSS JOIN Lieferanten li
 WHERE le.Liefstadt not like '' 
 AND li.Liefstadt not like '' 
 AND le.liefstadt=li.liefstadt
 AND le.Liefname < li.Liefname
```

I would recommend that you change the query to use joins so the conditions between the tables are obvious.

```
SELECT le.Liefname, le.liefstadt, li.Liefname
 FROM Lieferanten le JOIN
      Lieferanten li
      on le.liefstadt=li.liefstadt and
         le.Liefname < li.Liefname
 WHERE le.Liefstadt not like '' and 
       li.Liefstadt not like ''
```

Although not required, using the `on` clause for conditions comparing fields in two tables generates more readable and maintainable queries than putting those conditions in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out, i guess you are right with the conditions, it seems to be way more clear than the Crossjoin approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `a.LiefName < b.LiefName` to always list the smallest name first.  If necessary, add `DISTINCT` if there are duplicates in the table itself.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.LiefName
,       b.LiefName
,       a.LiefStadt
FROM    Lieferanten a
JOIN    Lieferanten b 
ON      a.LiefStadt = b.LiefStadt 
WHERE   a.LiefStadt <> ''
        and a.LiefName < b.LiefName
```